# Code to track the no of data already entered

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2007

I have a form where i want to enter Sr. Nos for machines.it have a combo box where i have to choose the invoice no saved in another table along with its corresponding qty of machines.
When i am entering machine details it should say me as "enter Sr no. for X'th/Y'th machine where y is the total qty saved in db and x is the no. of sr no. i have saved+1  "

It should also allow me to save the no. some where.. i mean in any variable so that if i pause my work in between and after word if continue it should say me "enter detail for X'th/Y'th" not "1'st/Y'th"

I am using this code:

```
Private Sub get_qty()

    Dim qtySql As String = "SELECT * FROM invoice1 where chalan_no='" & cmbChal_no.Text & "'"
    cnnOLEDB.Open()
    Dim cmd As OleDb.OleDbCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(qtySql, cnnOLEDB)

    Dim dr As OleDb.OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader

    If dr.Read = True Then
        qnty = dr("qty")
    End If

    cnnOLEDB.Close()

End Sub

Private Sub Srno_enter()

    Dim noSql As String = "SELECT count(sr_no) FROM Vendor_machine GROUP BY(chalan_no) having chalan_no='" & cmbChal_no.Text & "'"
    cnnOLEDB.Open()
    Dim cmd As OleDb.OleDbCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(noSql, cnnOLEDB)

       ' Suggest code retrieve count(sr_no)           <--------------------------

    cnnOLEDB.Close()

End Sub

private sub show()
     lblMachine= 'Result of count(sr_no)' "/" qnty
end sub
```

Please suggest me the code for same.. thank you..

Answer (score 1):

Just use an [Identity column](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_column) in your database and let the database engine do the work of creating the next free number.

If you wrote a stored procedure to do the insert, you could [return the serial number as an output parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142444/stored-procedure-return-identity-as-output-parameter-or-scalar)

Comment: @Harabati - Read the links in the answer - they give you all the elaboration

Comment: I mean if i have 20 machines in one invoice no..then it should tell me to enter details for 1st/2nd/3rd../20 machine.   And also if i have entered details for 10 machines and due to some reasons i have to stop the system and later when i start it should say enter details for 11th/20th machine not 1st/20th machine...      If any one can help me please.....its very very urgent.... Thank you..

Comment: @Harabati - it seems to me like you need to look into the design of your database first. The serial numbers table should be a related table to the invoices table and allow you to enter any number of serial numbers. Then use a foreign key in the serial numbers table to link back to the invoices table. Working out how many serial numbers have been entered against an invoice is then trivial: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SerialNos WHERE SerialNos.InvoiceID = 1234`

Comment: I am using the same query, i think kits working... but how to set it as label text... code:                                            `Dim strCntSr As String = "SELECT count(sr_no) FROM Vendor_Machine WHERE chaln_no='" & cmbChal_no.Text & "'"                            
    dim comm_getCnt = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(strCntSr, cnnOLEDB)
        comm_getCnt.ExecuteNonQuery()
        a = Val(comm_getCnt.ToString)
        lblMachine.Text = a & "/" & qnty`                           I know this is not the correct code.. plz suggest me the correct code for this... Thank you..