# get the id of the last inserted row in

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I saw few solutions here but none worked. I tried `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` didn't wotk. the id is autoincrement.

This is my stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[uploadVid]
    @video varbinary(MAx),
    @vidTitle varchar(50),
    @vidCategory varchar(50),
    @vidDate date,
    @vidDescription varchar(Max),
    @vidName varchar(50),
    @vidSize bigint
AS

INSERT INTO Video(video, vidTitle, vidCategory, vidDate, vidDescription, vidName, vidSize)
VALUES (@video, @vidTitle, @vidCategory, @vidDate, @vidDescription, @vidName, @vidSize)
```

& in the back end I tried

```
Object i = register.ExecuteScalar();
```

&

```
int newId = (Int32)register.ExecuteScalar();
```

I put a break point and it gave me a value of null or 0. any help appreciated

Thanks

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Consider using an `output parameter` to get back the new id, as return value is used for error handling : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142444/stored-procedure-return-identity-as-output-parameter-or-scalar

Comment: A stored procedure call from ADO.NET sample here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/59x02y99

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[uploadVid]
    @video varbinary(MAx),
    @vidTitle varchar(50),
    @vidCategory varchar(50),
    @vidDate date,
    @vidDescription varchar(Max),
    @vidName varchar(50),
    @vidSize bigint
AS
begin

declare @id as int --assuming your identity column is int

INSERT INTO Video(video, vidTitle, vidCategory, vidDate, vidDescription, vidName, vidSize)
VALUES (@video, @vidTitle, @vidCategory, @vidDate, @vidDescription, @vidName, @vidSize)

set @id = scope_identity()
select @id --return the value for executescaler to catch it
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you don't execute the commands in the correct sequence: (supposing you are using an SQL Server DB)

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("uploadVid", connnection);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.Add(.....)
......
// After adding the parameters you execute the command to insert the new row....
int rowsInserted = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
if(rowsInserted > 0)
{

    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()", connection);
    int newID = (int)cmd1.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

`ExecuteScalar` returns only the value of the first row in the first column of the query executed. In case of an insert this value is meaningless. You need an `ExecuteNonQuery` that returns the rows inserted by the command. After that run a new command with the `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` command text with the ExecuteScalar. This, of course, if you cannot modify the SP, the answer from th1rdey3 is better if you could change the proc because it avoids a run-trip to the database.

Comment: No need to execute another SqlCommand, returning SCOPE_IDENTITY() from the stored procedure should do the trick. See th1rdey3's answer.

Comment: @DudePascalou Does my answer gives a wrong result? Did you know if he could change the SP? While the other answer could be better I don't think that mine deserve downvoting. Well that's your choice.

Comment: He did not tell us if he can modify the SP. If he cannot, you're right, that is a way to do. And I am sorry about the downvoting. But if he can, this way is not recommended, because you can return the id in only one command.