# PHP/mySQL Insert then get id by calling a stored procedure

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, mysqli, insert

I have an ID field of type int that auto increments whenever I insert a row.

Is `mysql_insert_id()` gets the inserted row when I do this

```
mysql_query("call AddUser($user,$pass);");
```

I was wondering if it will get the ID when calling a stored proc.

Comment: This might be of some help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3143038/2518525

Comment: thanks, that gave me the most crucial clue, it is last_insert_id() for mySQL, same as scope_identity()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a stored procedure then you have no real access to what's going on in that procedure unless the procedure itself passes the information out. You can, therefore, define an OUT parameter to the procedure and return the last_insert_id() value in that:

**Procedure**

```
delimiter $$
drop procedure if exists p$$
CREATE PROCEDURE p(OUT InsertId int) 
BEGIN
insert test.Numbers (Numbers) values (3);
select last_insert_id() into InsertId ;

END$$
delimiter ;
```

**Call with a mysqli query**

```
call p(@InsertId);
```

**Then retrieve the result with another mysqli query**

```
select @InsertId as id;
```

Note - the variables live for the life of the connection so unless you close the connection you can retrieve the value of @InsertId whenever it's convenient.

Thanks to Patchrick for adding the PHP niceties:

```
$acct = mysql_query("call p(@InsertId);select @InsertId as id;");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($acct);
echo $row["id"];
```

Comment: so when using it on php, $acct = mysql_query("call p(@InsertId); select @InsertId as id;"); $row = mysql_fetch_array($acct); echo $row["id"];

Comment: FYI - I found that I needed to do the "select @InsertId as id;" call as a separate MySQL query using mysqli in PHP7.