# Returning recordset and return value in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have stored procedure A which before ending:

```
SELECT scope_identity() autoid
RETURN 0;
```

I then have stored procedure B that calls A as such:

```
EXEC @idvalue = EXEC spA
```

I need to get the autoid value from spA into spB.

Changing spA is not an option. Is this possible and how?

Everything else in the sp's work I'm just getting the return value from spA instead of the autoid.

Comment: Is that SELECT the *only* SELECT? If so then `CREATE TABLE #x(id INT); INSERT #x EXEC dbo.spA; SELECT TOP (1) @idvalue = id FROM #x;`

Comment: Is that the only way?  Seems a bit heavy just to return an integer.

Comment: Since you are wanting to return a scalar value just use an OUTPUT parameter.

Comment: Just noticed you have a variable named @scope_identity...that seems a little strange but without more context it is hard to say what is going on.

Comment: @scope_identity is the last inserted auto incremented field within the scope of the stored proedcure where @@IDENTITY is global.  I can't modify spA without also modifying i don't know how many lines of C# code. (For the record this is not my doing, I'm just the inheriting code monkey :)

Comment: @Wranorn Consider this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3142510), may be useful

Comment: I hear you about inheriting however @scope_identity is a variable here not the function SCOPE_IDENTITY(). I fully understand the differences but noticed it was a variable which struck me as a bit strange. Darn previous developers. :)

Comment: Whoops, edited for correctness

Comment: @Sean `Changing spA is not an option.`

Comment: @chridam Thank you for the comment, but I can't change the procedure parameters, it will break in a number of projects software as they will complain that the nth parameter isn't provided.

Comment: @Wranom to be fair, adding an output parameter that is nullable should not break any existing code that calls the stored procedure. You should state in the question that that's the reason changing the stored procedure "is not an option" - I assumed you didn't have control of the procedure or vendor policies prohibited modification.

Comment: @AaronBertrand It's the way the stored procedures are used.  The program does, for lack of a better term, auto discovery of the parameters of the stored procedures and maps data to specific parameter names.  Since it doesn't know how to deal with that specific parameter, it will cause issues.  I tried it, that's how I know it will freak out.  (and I could fix that if I had access to that source).

Comment: Yes, it seems a bit heavy, but you've placed roadblocks on the lighter (and better) approach, which is to use an output parameter.

Comment: @AaronBertrand your solution worked, if you don't mind posting it as an answer, and waiting a bit to see if someone has a lighter solution, I'll be happy to mark it as the answer.

Comment: I think I'm just going to quit my job and I won't have to deal with it :/

Answer (score 0):

Please use the OUT parameter, and pass it to another procedure. This is only the best way

Comment: Best way yes, only way, no.   As I said, at this point in time, it's not an option to do so.  Aaron ' solution does work for what I need.