# How can i get the row id that inserted via stored procedure?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

```
Model model=new Model();
model.id=0;
model.name="";
model.surname="";
db.Model.Add(model);
db.SaveChanges();
int id_returned=model.id;
```

This block gives me the id field of the inserted row.

But i use stored procedure for this insert process.

```
Model model=new Model();
model.id=0;
model.name="";
model.surname="";
int returned_id2=db.Sp_Model_insert(model.name, model.surname);
```

this block inserts the row. **returned_id2** returns **-1**.

How can i get the row id that inserted via Sp ?

Here is my Stored Procedure:

```
USE [KayaShop]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [KS_ACCOUNTS].[SP_AccountModules_Insert](
@Area nvarchar(50),
@Controller nvarchar(50),
@Action nvarchar(50),
@SubAction nvarchar(50),
@Name nvarchar(50),
@TopName nvarchar(50),
@Level int,
@Visible int,
@Clickable int,
@HomePage int,
@Icon nvarchar(20),
@Status int
)
AS 
BEGIN 
 SET NOCOUNT ON 
 INSERT INTO [KS_ACCOUNTS].[AccountModules]
       ([Area]
       ,[Controller]
       ,[Action]
       ,[SubAction]
       ,[Name]
       ,[TopName]
       ,[Level]
       ,[Visible]
       ,[Clickable]
       ,[HomePage]
       ,[Icon]
       ,[Status])
 VALUES
       (@Area,
       @Controller,
       @Action,
       @SubAction,
       @Name,
       @TopName,
       @Level,
       @Visible,
       @Clickable,
       @HomePage,
       @Icon,
       @Status)
END
```

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142444/stored-procedure-return-identity-as-output-parameter-or-scalar

Comment: It looks like you're using Entity Framework or some other ORM. If so, you should not perform the `INSERT` by yourself, let your ORM do it for you so you can take advantage of its state-tracking. Your ORM will automatically map and assign generated `IDENTITY` values back to your entity objects.

Comment: @dai yes. you are right. also i told this entity feature as you can see above. but i need to insert via SP.

Comment: @dai and yes i use entity framework.

Comment: @ysrtymz Why do you need to insert via Stored Procedure? What is the business-case? You don't need to restrict yourself to Sproc-based inserts for security, for example, as SQL Server lets you grant/deny access to individual DML statements, and auditing is better performed with triggers, too.

Comment: They told me that inserting via SP is faster than inserting without SP. thats why i use sp

Comment: @ysrtymz They're wrong. Sprocs are not faster at inserting than any other SQL (and the *really* faster way is `BULK INSERT` :D ). There is a long-running myth that Sprocs are faster than raw SQL - this dates back from earlier versions of SQL Server that cached execution plans (only for `SELECT` statements, I note), this hasn't been true since at least SQL Server 2000, so their information is both incorrect and 16 years out of date!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Add this after the insert query in your stored procedure

Answer (score 1):

Multiple ways:

- `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx - Returns the last single `IDENTITY` value in the current session's current scope.
- `@@IDENTITY` - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187342.aspx - Returns the last single `IDENTITY` value in the current session (regardless of scope).
- `INSERT INTO ... VALUES ... OUTPUT` - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx - outputs all inserted values, including `IDENTITY` values, this is the only way to retrieve `IDENTITY` values when your `INSERT` statement will insert multiple rows.

As your stored procedure only seems to insert a single row, you should be fine with `SCOPE_IDENTITY`.

Note that if all your stored procedure does is `INSERT` you probably don't need a stored procedure, your database client code should perform the `INSERT` directly.

Note that you should not use the `RETURN` keyword to return the `IDENTITY` value to the caller, you should use output parameters - a stored procedure's return-value is intended to convey status information and it is restricted to just an `int` value (e.g. return `0` for success).

Comment: i am very new to stored procedures. can you answer more specific please ?

Answer (score 0):

I added these lines to the end of my sp:

```
SELECT @Id =SCOPE_IDENTITY()
RETURN
```

and at my code side:

```
int Id = 0;
ObjectParameter prm = new ObjectParameter("Id", typeof(int));
DB.SP_AccountModules_Insert(DTO.Area, DTO.Controller, DTO.Action, DTO.SubAction, DTO.Name, DTO.TopName, DTO.Level, DTO.Visible, DTO.Clickable, DTO.HomePage, DTO.Icon, DTO.Status, prm);
Id = Convert.ToInt32(prm.Value);
return Id;
```

i send and out parameter from my code to my sp, then i assign the last inserted id to my parameter and return it to my code. thats it.
Thank you for all help.